# Editing options pages?

Tags: plugin-development, options

I'm trying to find a way of adding a single checkbox to one of the existing options pages, most likely options-reading.php programmatically. Unfortunately, I haven't found any good references on this. Any thoughts from the community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did some searching and found this in the codex:

```
add_settings_field( 'myprefix_setting-id', 'This is the setting title', 'myprefix_setting_callback_function', 'general', 'myprefix_settings-section-name', array( 'label_for' => 'myprefix_setting-id' ) );
```

Here is the link to the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field

Looks as simple as choosing the right slug like 'general' to add an option to the general settings page.

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: You, sir, are awesome. That and a little research led me to [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/issues-with-register_settingadd_settings_field), which solved my issue!